# IRAF Transform Task - ERROR (741, "Cannot open file(database)")

Tags: python, transform, astronomy, iraf

I am getting this error while doing the transform task in iraf.

```
transform input=hd75555lr_s0.5nhg_combine output=hd75555lr_s0.5nhg_combine_t fitnames=arglamplowr_s1.0-00053.Z-CROP interptype=linear flux=yes blank=INDEF x1=INDEF x2=INDEF dx=INDEF y1=INDEF y2=INDEF dy=INDEF
```

```
Killing IRAF task `transform`

Traceback (innermost last):
  
File "CL script CL1", line 1, in module

IrafError: Error running IRAF task transform

IRAF task terminated abnormally
ERROR (741, "Cannot open file (database/fcarglamplowr_s1.0-00053.Z-CROP)")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error came because I skipped a step before the transform task. IRAF was looking for a file that hasn't been created yet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).